# How to post data from text fields created clientside using webforms?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to send data from text fields created on the client side (via jquery). The problem is the data from those text boxes is not being post back ( I'm using asp.net webforms)

I have used fiddler to view the post back data and it isn't there for those generated text fields.

****Solved **
I'm surprised no one figured it out. I was switching from server to non server controls I forgot to give the non ones a name field..........**

```
 // Add answer field
    $('#addAnswer').click(function ()
    {
        count++;

        var html = '<p>' +
                        '<input id="answer' + count + '" type="text" maxlength="255" runat="server" />' +
                        '<a id="removeAnswer" class="removeIcon" href="#"><img class="removeIcon" src="/Content/images/minus.gif" /></a>' +
                    '</p>'

        $(html).appendTo('#answers');

        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have the "name" attribute on the regular html input fields, so it never registered them on the server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a dynamic server side control from the client side.

If I were to do this, I wouldn't use `runat="server"` on the input, as it will be meaningless. I would also ensure that I am appending it within the `form` tag. After doing this, I would look for the value within the [`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) collection.

Comment: I looked there, but the values are not showing up. they only show up when I use server controls, otherwise nothing is passed. I didn't realize webforms were so limiting.

Comment: @chobo - I have used html form elements within webforms before. Are you certain they are inserted within the server side form? How are you posting? Regardless - you will probably find ASP.NET/MVC much more to your liking.

Comment: I know all about MVC and it is a million times better :) Unfortunately this is some legacy site at work...

Comment: I have removed removed the masterpage so it is only my code now, and it still can't get the form elements that are not server-controls. I'm going to try the web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're adding the fields inside the FORM tags?  If so, you should be able to access the values via Request("answerN").

Comment: this is inside the asp.net <form runat="server" which encapsulates the entire page

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery code here wouldn't cause a postback since it is just manipulating the DOM locally. If you wanted to post something back to the server you would need to use the Ajax methods from jQuery. (I would just comment on your question, but I'm still building my rep)

http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/

Comment: I'm not trying to postback with JQuery (I gave up on that). The problem in simple terms is regular html forms controls like <input type="text"> does not show up in serverside on postback